# How to provide RPC interface in an Android system service?

Tags: android, android-source, rpc, android-binder

I'm developing a (native) service process whose executable resides on 
the system partition on Android 8.1/9.0. Let's call the process S. S
is supposed to provide RPC service to a process V whose executable
resides on the vendor partition. I read from Android Treble architecture
that system components are separated from vendor ones by HIDL
interfaces. Shall I use the callback interface in HIDL to accommodate
my need, or shall I use some other mechanisms such as AIDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the Hardware Binder context together with `HIDL`.

Background: There are now three Binder contexts:

1. Framework Binder (`/dev/binder`)
   This is for IPC on system/framework side only. This Binder context uses `AIDL`.
2. Vendor Binder (`/dev/vndbinder`)
   This is for IPC on vendor side only. This Binder context uses `AIDL` as well.
3. Hardware Binder (`/dev/hwbinder`)
   This context allows connecting services from the vendor side with services from the system/framework side. Since Trebles goal is to allow system and vendor partitions to be updated individually, `AIDL` wasn't safe enough anymore. Thus `HIDL` was introduced and is used by this context.